# Data migration tool installation error Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, error, installation, data-migration

I am facing below error when try to install data migration tool from command line.

[image]

I have fresh magento installation and I am trying to install data migration tool from repo.magento.com and following [official](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html) link.

Did anyone face this issue before?

Comment: you can follow below link this link work for me 
https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-migration

Comment: Yes @RakeshDonga, I know all the steps but not have any idea about this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue on command line try to download from the github with the same version here is a [link](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/releases)